# In Eclipse, how do I get my newly installed window builder to work with an existing project?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I have Eclipse on my Windows 10 laptop. Originally I did not have the "Window Builder" installed. I have it installed now, but my program is unable to see/use it. (Please, note that I am only posting the imports not working because the code is downloaded from my professor, and I do not wish to share someone else's code.)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
```

[image: Showing Installed Status of Window Builder]

[image: Showing the error squiggles]

[image: Showing Error test]

Comment: You must first fix the project problems to be able to use WindowBuilder which you have successfully installed. Please add the problem messages shown in the _Problems_ view to your question. If you have a `module-info.java`, delete it. Tell also which Java version you use in that project (unfortunately your screenshots are cropped, so it is not possible to see exactly what is wrong).

Comment: @howlger Yeah, I'm sorry about that, I may be being overly cautious but it is my professor's code I didn't want to show. However, you were right! I deleted module-info.java and it fixed those errors! So, thank you very much!